# QT slots and signals args

Tags: qt, qt-creator, signals-slots

I am new to Qt and stumbled across a problem that I could not find an answer for on Google.

Say I want to send an acceleration and velocity field. I define a custom signal :

```
setProperties(QString,double,double,bool)
```

However, how do I tell the difference between velocity and acceleration in such a statement?

```
connect(dialog, SIGNAL(setProperties(QString,double,double,bool)),
        this, SLOT(somerandomslot()));
```

`randomslot` needs to get the velocity field and acceleration fields and manipulate them, but in the above `SIGNAL` they are just `double`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case your `somerandomslot()` function should probably have a matching function signature so that the values `emit`ed in your signal can get passed to it:

```
void somerandomslot( const QString &foo, double a, double v, bool bar );
```

then your connect call would look like this:

```
connect(dialog, SIGNAL(setProperties(QString,double,double,bool)), this, SLOT(somerandomslot(QString, double, double, bool)));
```

and when your `somerandomslot()` gets called you'll have access to those variables.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for the response, but how does randomSlot tell apart the first double from the second double? ie will the first double from setProperties match up exactly with the first double from somerandomslot? thanks a bunch

Comment: It will come in the same order as the arguments passed to your signal when you called emit.  Just like any C++ function call.